# Using a for loop in JavaScript to loop over an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, javascript-objects

[My code and terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1PTG.png)

Just ignore the comments, they are in danish as it is for a school assignment..
I need some help. My loop keeps giving me an undefined value in my terminal, and I can't seem to find the issue. It is working as it should, and gives me the correct values, but still has those 'undefined' ones which irritates me.

EDIT: Has been fixed by @aqq, thx for the help everybody!

Comment: paste the code here or in codepen

Comment: `undefined` could be coming from those `gorBeskedPersonlig()` calls

Comment: @aqq const katalog = [{
    navn: 'Sigurd',
    sang: 'Hit me baby one more time'
},
{
    navn: 'Tessa',
    sang: 'Ben'
},
{
    navn: 'Mia',
    sang: 'Love will tear us apart'

}]

const playliste = []

for (let index = 0; index < katalog.length; index++) {
    const element = katalog[index];
    playliste.push(element.sang);
    console.log(gørBeskedPersonlig(katalog[index].navn));
    
}
console.log(playliste);

Comment: @dikuw - hmm I really need those calls, while it is from an earlier array in the same code... Are there any other ways i could use the gørBeskedPersonlig function and having the loop input the 3 names in it?

Comment: @MakiZ420 edit your question to add the `gørBeskedPersonlig` function

Comment: @MakiZ420 or put it in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3njt4avk/

Comment: Where's the source for `gørBeskedPersonalig`? Could it be expecting you to pass in more than just the `navn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dikuw mentioned the undefined call might be coming from the gørBeskedPersonlig function being called.

I don't see that function being defined in your code so that's probably it, try commenting out the following line:

```
console.log(gørBeskedPersonlig(katalog[index].navn));
```

UPDATE: After reviewing your code, i can see that the function gørBeskedPersonlig was not returning anything.

Updating it to return the new value has fixed the "undefined" error.

```
function gørBeskedPersonlig(navn){
    hemmeligBesked.splice(1,1,navn+'!');
    return hemmeligBesked.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. is there any way I can show you all of my code? Because gørBeskedPersonlig is a function splicing and joining another array.. Then you can see all of the context :) I tried c+p'ing it here, but it is too long for that..

Comment: https://codepen.io/MakiZ420/pen/QWgVwyW?editors=0010 i don't know if you can open this link, but I have now stored all of my code on codePen for a better reference.

Comment: @MakiZ420 check the updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! Always nice to get help in here, as a newbie to JS!

Comment: @MakiZ420 np :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some console.log() in function gørBeskedPersonlig that is returning undefined. Send a code for that function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).